# Exceeding the 65535 bytes limit onItemClick

Tags: android

I have a listview it fetch data from another activity. And I have 1 thousand if loop. When user click list item then an alert dialog opens. Until yesterday I add all data's info's with alert but today. Warning appears.

It's my list;

```
ListView sonuclistesi=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.sonuclistesi);
ArrayAdapter<String> veriadaptoru=new Listeozellikleri(this,veriler);
sonuclistesi.setAdapter(veriadaptoru);
```

It's list's onclick event;

```
sonuclistesi.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
String veri = veriler.get(position).toString();

if(veri.equals("car")){
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(sonuclar.this).create();
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.dialog_animation;
                alertDialog.setTitle("Car");
                alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.car);
                alertDialog.setMessage(sonuclar.this.getString(R.string.car));

                        alertDialog.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, sonuclar.this.getString(R.string.kapat), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()    {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            };


                    });             


                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.getButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#445981"));
                alertDialog.getButton(alertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#445981"));   
            }
          //... 1 thousand if again and again...

        }
    });
```

So what can I do? I read a few article about divide method. But there are not working for me...

Comment: 1000 ??? would you consoder to refactory that instead??

Comment: I must do it with this way..

Comment: `today. Warning appears.`. Which warning? At wich moment?

Comment: Warning is, exceeding the 65535 bytes limit at onItemClick. This code is not all. In my project there are 1 thousand "if block" I need to add more but this warning appears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing your hitting is the 65K class limit in a dex file.  If you're hitting this, unless you're writing facebook  you're doing something horribly wrong.  If you're writing code and you're ever pasting more than 2 or 3 if statements like above, you're doing it wrong.  If you actually thought this was the right way to do it.... I don't think I can teach you how to do it correctly in the space of an answer here.  I suggest you take a course on programming fundamentals, particularly object oriented programming and abstraction.  You don't actually know how to program.

Comment: So how can I do it correctly can you explain it? If data is car I want to show a pop up and give info. How can I do it with less code?

Comment: Use a single on click listener class that takes in parameters for the mutable parts, rather than literally 1000 anonymous classes.